# Max Heap with ArrayList

Tags: java, sorting, insert, queue

I made a class to manage a Priority Queue with an ArrayList as parameter. I need to do a Max Heap, so if I do the following insert: 16, 9, 7, 8, 4, 14, 1, 3, 2, 10 I need to get an ArrayList with these elements in these position: {16, 9, 14, 7, 4, 8, 10, 3, 2, 1}. The problem is that my insert method looks like doesn't order the elements:

```
public void insert(T elem) {
    int i = queue.size();
    int parentIndex = (int) Math.floor((i - 1) / 2);
    while (i > 0 && elem.compareTo(queue.get(parentIndex)) == 1) {
      queue.set(i, queue.get(parentIndex));
      i = parentIndex;
      parentIndex = (int) Math.floor((i - 1) / 2);
    }
    queue.add(i, elem);
  }
```

Example: insert(16), insert(14), insert(9). Array expected: {16,9,14}. Result: {16,14,9}.

Comment: So what output do you get? Edit your question to show the input, expected output, and actual output.

Comment: Question edited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your expectation is unrealistic. `{16, 14, 9}` is a perfectly valid binary heap.

A binary heap must maintain two properties:

1. The shape property - It is a complete binary tree: a tree in which all levels, except possibly the last, are completely full. If not full, the last level is left-filled.
2. The heap property - In a max heap, every node is greater than or equal to its children. In a min heap, every node is less than or equal to its children.

So all of these are valid binary max heaps of 4 items:

```
      4          4          4
    2   3      3   2      3   1
   1          1          2
```

The key here is that in each case, the largest value is at the root, and children are always smaller than their parents.

The order of nodes in a binary heap is dependent on the insertion order. In your example, if the insertion order were `{16, 9, 14}`, then you would get the order you expected.

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_heap for more information about binary heaps.

I think the issue you're struggling with is the expectation that a priority queue maintains a sorted list. It doesn't. Priority queue is simply the name for a data structure that allows insertion, and removal of the highest priority item. You *could* implement a priority queue with a sorted list, but doing so would be very expensive. The binary heap is a better choice in terms of performance.

If, after you add all the items to your priority queue, you called the remove method (or whatever you call the method that gets the largest item) repeatedly, you would see that items are removed in the proper order.

Comment: In my formula I have to considerer that the 2i position are for the left son and that the 2i+1 position are for the right son. This is why I expect {16, 9, 14}

Comment: Your formula still works with the [16, 14, 9] arrangement. There is no requirement that the left child be less than the right child.